# Installing library with easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install

I am trying to install a library for sparse matrices called `sparsesvd`.  When I use either `easy_install` or `pip` I get an error, for not finding a file.

I also tried downloading the library, and installing it manually with `sudo python setup.py install`, but the same error appears.

The error basically reads like this:

```
Error: /...some directories.../README.rst: No such file or directory
```

Does someone know what the problem might be?
Thank you in advance. 
Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the file setup.py and the file test.py I have replaced the line load(README.rst) by load(README.txt) and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best idea but since it's just a README file just make a dummy empty file in that exact path.

Comment: Pragmatic approach :) Indeed it might be a good idea, the library might just work and then it might be a good idea to get in touch with the people behind it and inform them of the issue.

Comment: Awesome hopefully it doesn't make the library buggy.

Answer (score 1):

The package located at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stashy/0.1 is apparently not maintained, it hasn't any `requirements.txt` either.

I cloned the source from github - it worked:

```
git clone https://github.com/RisingOak/stashy.git
cd stashy
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing it and it seems it's broken (the setup.py file is broken at line 37 - it tries to read this README.rst file). So perhaps you should contact the authors of the library.

Comment: as I said above, the README file is a text .txt file not a .rst file